# connect by prior oracle

Tags: oracle, recursive-query, connect-by

I have a table that contains an hierarchic element

Table :

```
A       B 
P1      -
P2      P1
C1      P2
C2      P2
```

B is a foreign key coming from the same table

The query is :

```
SELECT level niveau, A
from table parent, table child
START WITH A IN
( 'P0','P1','C2')
CONNECT BY PRIOR  A= B
```

The result

```
1 P1
1 P2
  2 C1
  2 C2
1 C2
```

Why the "2 C2" apears?

The result desired is in spite of it's not the correct, i:

```
1 P1
1 P2
  2 C1
1 C2
```

Comment: `2 C2` appears because `C2` is a child of `P2`.

Answer (score 2):

`Connect by` condition is evaluated first, `start with` later. In your case C2 is both a child of P2 AND a root of the hierarchy. This is why it appears in your result twice.

From [Oracle Documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

> Oracle processes hierarchical queries as follows:
>
> A join, if present, is evaluated first, whether the join is specified
>   in the FROM clause or with WHERE clause predicates.
>
> The CONNECT BY condition is evaluated.
>
> Any remaining WHERE clause predicates are evaluated.
>
> Oracle then uses the information from these evaluations to form the
>   hierarchy using the following steps:
>
> Oracle selects the root row(s) of the hierarchy--those rows that
>   satisfy the START WITH condition.
>
> Oracle selects the child rows of each root row. Each child row must
>   satisfy the condition of the CONNECT BY condition with respect to one
>   of the root rows.
>
> Oracle selects successive generations of child rows. Oracle first
>   selects the children of the rows returned in step 2, and then the
>   children of those children, and so on. Oracle always selects children
>   by evaluating the CONNECT BY condition with respect to a current
>   parent row.
>
> If the query contains a WHERE clause without a join, then Oracle
>   eliminates all rows from the hierarchy that do not satisfy the
>   condition of the WHERE clause. Oracle evaluates this condition for
>   each row individually, rather than removing all the children of a row
>   that does not satisfy the condition.
>
> Oracle returns the rows in the order shown in Figure 9-1. In the
>   diagram, children appear below their parents. For an explanation of
>   hierarchical trees,

Comment: Can you adjust my query to be like wanted?

Comment: it is your data that is incorrect, not your query: C2, P2 pair should either go or be replaced with (C2,null)

Answer (score 0):

set one node to be the root node mean it must be start with one node then it will work for you I had the same problem I hope this help you

```
SELECT level niveau, A
from table parent, table child
START WITH A IN ='P1'
CONNECT BY PRIOR  A= B
```